# Can I access static/admin/js/urlify.js on pythonanywhere.com?

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I want to modify this file:

http://name.pythonanywhere.com/static/admin/js/urlify.js

Specifically, to remove the stop words in:

var removeList = [];

I had no problem doing this on my local machine.

On pythonanywhere I did the same thing to the two urlify.js files I could find:

~/name.pythonanywhere.com/static/admin/js/urlify.js

/home/name/.virtualenvs/.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/urlify.js

But the active file remains unchanged at:

http://name.pythonanywhere.com/static/admin/js/urlify.js

Can I, in fact, access and edit my urlify.js file on pythonanywhere?

Comment: You should be able to change it, yes.  There's a help page on debugging static file issues on PythonAnywhere's help site: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles/

Comment: Thanks. These instructions have been helpful.